# ES log loading error...... (Springboot - elastic,kibana) I'm really going crazy

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, logback

#### Version

1. springboot - 3.1.6
2. 'logback-elasticsearch-appender', version: '1.6'
3. 'logback-access-spring-boot-starter', version: '4.1.0'

#### - Below is the logback-access-spring.xml I wrote.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <springProperty scope="context" name="elasticsearch_uris" source="spring.elasticsearch.uris" defaultValue="http://~~~~~~"/>
    <appender name="ELASTIC" class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAccessAppender">
        <url>${elasticsearch_uris}/_bulk</url>
        <index>searchterm-%date{yyyy-MM-dd}</index>
        <properties>
            <property name="contentLength" value="length"/>
            <property name="remoteHost" value="%h"/>
            <property name="protocol" value="%H"/>
            <property name="referer" value="%i{Referer}"/>
            <property name="userAgent" value="%i{User-Agent}"/>
            <property name="requestMethod" value="%m"/>
            <property name="statusCode" value="%s"/>
            <property name="elapsedTime" value="%D"/>
            <property name="date" value="%t{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss}"/>
            <property name="user" value="%u"/>
            <property name="queryString" value="%q"/>
            <property name="requestURI" value="%U"/>
        </properties>

        <headers>
            <header>
                <name>Content-Type</name>
                <value>application/json</value>
            </header>
        </headers>
    </appender>

    <appender-ref ref="ELASTIC" />
</configuration>
```

#### - If you send logs to elastic using logback, no fields are created in the index pattern. Why?

### **Actual**

```
{
        "_index": "searchterm-2023-12-13",
        "_id": "bO4gYowB_nCChb6LIW4h",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": "2023-12-13T16:42:01.733+0900"
        }
```

### **Expected**

```
{
        "_index" : "application-accesslog-2023-02-06",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "sQsnJYYBczPF6ol6vVuF",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2023-02-06T14:16:46.531+0900",
          "contentLength" : "82",
          "remoteHost" : "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "protocol" : "HTTP/1.1",
          "referer" : "-",
          "userAgent" : "PostmanRuntime/7.29.2",
          "requestMethod" : "POST",
          "statusCode" : "200",
          "elapsedTime" : "330",
          "date" : "2023-02-06T14:16:46",
          "user" : "-",
          "requestURI" : "/performance/documents"
        }
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.